# What does 'SSSXXX' mean in a java simple date format object?

Tags: java

I've found this in some legacy code that I don't understand. Does anyone know what the SSSXXX bit means, it seems to be adding 2 hours to my date!?

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```

Comment: Tone - this is what they write javadocs for.

Answer (score 10):

According to [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `S` refers to milliseconds and `X` to the timezone.

The "Examples" section contains an example of `SSSXXX` yielding a three digit millisecond representation followed by a "full" timezone offset "-07:00". `XX` would have resulted in the medium format "-0700" and `X` simply "-07".

Comment: The API even contains an example of that exact format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" ==> 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00

Comment: @sheltem Indeed - updated answer to reflect :) Thanks for hinting.